# How to upgrade the version of php-gd library when running from php-fpm at Ubuntu 16.04 server?

Tags: php, ubuntu, gd, fpm, ispconfig

I've followed this tutorial to install and support PHP-5.6 at my ISPConfig3 server: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-php-5-6-on-ubuntu-16-04/.

The installation is up and running, now I want to change the php-gd library version. PHP info actually reports:

```
GD Support  enabled

GD Version  bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
```

I need to use the following version:

```
GD Support  enabled

GD headers Version  2.2.3

GD library Version  2.2.3
```

**Why do i need to upgrade?**

I'm facing problems when cropping images, but is only on this server. I've a similar server with PHP-5.6, without fpm, that is working fine. I realized the difference in versions after compare the phpinfo() reports from both servers

**Expected Behavior**

1. User uploads an image. The image can have any dimension. (eg: 1920x1080)
2. The script resizes the image. (eg: from 1920px to 1200px)
3. The resized image maintain it's original aspect ratio and should not be cropped.
   See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YW8N4.jpg

**The problem**

1. User uploads an image. The image can have any dimension. (eg: 1920x1080)
2. The script SHOULD resize the image. (eg: from 1920px to 120px)
3. The final image was cropped erroneously :(
   See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKwxQ.jpg

Since i'm using php-fpm, how can i upgrade my GD library version?

Comment: It's generally best to stick to the supported version from your package manager. Is there something in 2.2 you absolutely must have?

Comment: I'm facing problems when cropping images, but is only on this server. I've a similar server with PHP-5.6, without fpm, that is working fine. I realized the difference in versions after compare the phpinfo() reports from both servers.

Comment: Could you share the problems? We might be able to assist with those.

Comment: I'll update the question, providing the actual and expected behaviors...

Comment: updated, added links to images. Plz tell me if it is not clear yet

Comment: Switch to ondrej ppa: https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php It has GD 2.2.3

Comment: @RicardoVigatti Can you share the code being used to generate these?

Comment: @mkaatman ondrej's php version is great, actually, i have it installed, but i don't know how to make it work with php-fpm in my ISPConfig server.

Comment: @ceejayoz, it's kind of hard to share the code cause it's a legacy system. The point here is that it's working in another simillar installation, remember? Anyway, i'll search for some code blocks that may help

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your comments until now. So, i was able to build ondrej's version of php-5.6 with the correct gd version. Well, the problem still happening. Now i have no hope, I can't imagine why the resizing isn't working as expected. The only difference in servers, reported by phpinfo, is the Server API option. Working server has Server API Apache 2.0 Handler while the other is using FPM/FastCGI.

Comment: If you run phpinfo(); does it show you the correct version of GD? You should probably post a new question with a [mcve] so we can troubleshoot.

Comment: @mkaatman thank you for your reply. I'll need to dig further into this issue before i can post a new question. The problem didn't seems to be what i was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

After long hours digging, I finally found the problem, and as i expected, it's not related to GD library itself. It's related to phpThumb and imagemagick libraries.